# Laravel - как сохранить связанные модели

Tags: laravel, mvc, eloquent, blade

товарищи!

Прошу помощи в следующем вопрос:

- Существует две модели: Order и OrderProducts.
- OrderProducts связана с Order через belongsTo

Задача:
При создании/сохранении Order через контроллер создавать/сохранять и OrderProducts.
При этом количество OrderProducts неизвестно (может быть 0, может 1 и может и 100).

Что непонимаю:

- Как в request в метод контроллера залить данные с формы с blade-шаблона
- Как из request в методе контроллера получить список данных для OrderProducts
- Как сохранить сами данные из request.

Comment: Кроме belongsTo, должен быть еще и hasMany у модели Order. А еще лучше, на мой взгляд, сделать отношение многие ко многим (многие Orders к многим Products через OrderProduct).

Comment: Чтобы передать данные из формы в код, надо отправить обычный запрос, никаких особых особенностей ))) в отправке формы нету. ЕДИНСТВЕННОЕ, кроме самой формы нужно передать еще и [CSRF-токен](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#csrf-field). Если никаких ошибок не вылетело, то данные должны окзаться [request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests). Сохранить в eloquent можно с помощью метода [create](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes)